# /etc/sudoers file ignored or overrriden somehow?

Tags: sudo

Here are the contents of my `/etc/sudoers` file

```
$ sudo cat /etc/sudoers
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

pkaramol ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

And here is what's inside `/etc/sudoers.d`

```
/home/pkaramol
$ sudo ls /etc/sudoers.d/
README
```

However, still no password-less sudo:

```
/home/pkaramol
$ sudo -k
/home/pkaramol
$ sudo -i
[sudo] password for pkaramol:
```

Why is that?

Comment: I agree it is a duplicate and we can close it

Answer (score 1):

`pkaramol` is a member of group `sudo` or `admin` - which requieres password to escalate privileges.

Comment: I removed me from `sudo` group and still the same

Comment: Please change also record for approriate group, for example
`%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`